# Hibernate : strategy=GenerationType value for oracle

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

My entity class :

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="APP_INSTANCE")
public class ApplicationEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="INSTANCE_KEY")
    private int INSTANCE_KEY;
 //other code 
}
```

My Table Structure :

```
CREATE TABLE "APP_INSTANCE" 
("INSTANCE_KEY" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"SYS_ID" VARCHAR2(255) , 
"NAME" VARCHAR2(255) , 
"ENV" VARCHAR2(50) , 
PRIMARY KEY ("APP_INSTANCE_KEY") ENABLE
 )
```

I am using Spring 3, Hibernate 4 and oracle database.While running my application iam gettin gbelow error :

```
03:23:07,380 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: insert into USER.APP_INSTANCE (SYS_ID, NAME, ENV) values (?, ?, ?)
03:23:08,271 INFO  [STDOUT] WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
03:23:08,271 INFO  [STDOUT] ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("USER"."APP_INSTANCE"."INSTANCE_KEY")
03:23:08,271 INFO  [STDOUT] Exception in saving..
03:23:08,271 ERROR [STDERR] org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
03:23:08,271 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:74)
03:23:08,271 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
03:23:08,271 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124)
```

I have also tried `GenerationType.AUTO` but then i got somthing like `sequence not found`.

Please help.I know that problem is related to `@GeneratedValue`. Please let me know the value for above table nad oracle database.

Comment: as far as I remember, Oracle use sequences so you need `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`

Comment: @Atha : SO i just need to replace GenerationType.IDENTITY to GenerationType.SEQUENCE in my entity class.Right.DO i need to do anything at DB side as well ( like need to create any sequence etc ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create sequence in oracle databae:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_APP_INSTANCE
 START WITH     1
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;
```

and annotate id to use this sequence:

```
@GeneratedValue(generator="seq_item", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq_item",sequenceName="SEQ_APP_INSTANCE", allocationSize=10)
@Column(name="INSTANCE_KEY")
private int INSTANCE_KEY;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GenericGenerator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/GenericGenerator.html) class of hibernate.

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
private int INSTANCE_KEY;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set this on your INSTANCE_KEY field:

```
@Id
@Column(name="INSTANCE_KEY")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqInstanceKey")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqInstanceKey", sequenceName = "SEQ_INSTANCE_KEY", allocationSize = 1)
private int INSTANCE_KEY;
```

And in your DB you add a sequence with name 'SEQ_INSTANCE_KEY' with property increment by = '1'