# JPA with ORACLE insert null error

Tags: java, oracle, exception, jpa, constraints

I have a JPA entity named "Service" having ID as primary key

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;
```

When I am trying to persist this data through JPA persistence API

```
Service service = new Service("abcservice");    
entityManager.persist(service);
```

I am getting error

```
cannot insert NULL into ("TESTUSER992"."SERVICE"."ID")
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.dto.Service]
```

I am using Oracle thin, sid:xe

Comment: Maybe a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693015/hibernate-strategy-generationtype-value-for-oracle

Answer (score 3):

Oracle doesn't support auto generated column, like MySQL or Postgres. You will have to use sequence, or table for generating ids, or set one manually in your code.

Sequence example:

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(generator="ServiceIdSeq", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE) 
@SequenceGenerator(name="ServiceIdSeq", sequenceName="SERVICE_ID_SEQ")
private long id;
```

Table example:

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(generator="ServiceIdTab", strategy=GenerationType.TABLE) 
@TableGenerator(name="ServiceIdTab", table="SEQUENCE_ID_GEN", 
    pkColumnName="ID_NAME", valueColumnName="ID_VAL", 
    pkColumnValue="SERVICE_GEN")
private long id;
```

**UPDATE**

Execute this in your database to create sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SERVICE_ID_SEQ INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Comment: I tried both of these but getting error. error: `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException`: could not get next sequence value

Comment: @ImranTariq You will need to create a sequence in DB for this to work. Check my updated answer. It will create a sequence that is configured in first example.

Comment: Having same error again after using sequence and table.

Comment: No need to try it out with `@TableGenerator`, the `create sequence` code is just for the `@SequenceGenerator` example. Any more details in the exception stack trace? `Caused by: Sequence does not exist` or something similar?

Comment: 'javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:' could not get next sequence value

Comment: @ImranTariq I don't see a reason for that exception, except the sequence name in the database isn't the same as on the entity. Other than that, you can print out the generated SQL and check what's going on. [In this blog](http://javadigest.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/using-the-sequence-generator-in-hibernate/) there is a simple example for configuring sequence generated ids, it should be pretty straight forward.